# Typescript mixins doesn't work with generic from parent

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement mixins in typescript and get autocomplete from the mixin class also. Here's my code:

```
export type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export interface Test {
  methodA();
  methodB();
}


export type TestCtor = Constructor<Test>;


export function mixinTest<T extends Constructor<{}>>(base: T): TestCtor & T {
  return class extends base {

    constructor(...args: any[]) { super(...args); }

    methodA() { }

    methodB() {}

  };
}

class A<T> { 
  value: T;

  constructor(param: string) {}
}

class B extends mixinTest(A<{id: string}>) {
}

new B().methodA();
```

> But I'm getting the error: No base constructor has the number
>   specified of arguments

or with the generic:

> expected 1 argument but got 3

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

```
....
class _Base extends A<{ id: string }> { }

class B extends mixinTest(_Base) {
}

new B('Hey!').methodA();
```